# Configuring the authentification for network access under windows xp

Tags: networking, windows-xp

I'm currently configuring the network authentification on a few windows xp machines. There I found that there are some differences in the display where I'm not sure if something needs to be done or not.

Some machines have 3 tabs at their connectin properties: General, Authentication, Advanced. While others have 2 tabs.

For those with the 3 tabs I need to go to authentication and modify the certificate they use there.

Now the 2 tabs property window is irritating there for me.  Does that mean that that is a different subversion of windows xp? Or that it does not have the option to set/change how it authentificate itself? Or is that moved to another screen?

Thus my question here summed up is: How can I change the authentification in a 2 tabs local area connection properties window (if at all)?

Comment: Screen shots would be nice...

Answer (score 2):

Are these Windows XP Professional machines? They may have a GPO that prevents changing those settings. I would check first if they are on a domain, and if so, I would look for a GPO that prevents access. You can output the GPOs that affect a system with the following command in CMD:

```
gpresult /H gpos.html
```

If they are not on a domain, note that there is still the possibility to set a local group policy. You can view the local Group Policy via `Start` > `Run` > `gpedit.msc` > `OK`.

I believe the policy you are looking for should be located around:

```
Computer Configuration\ Policies \Windows Settings\Security Settings\Wired Network (IEEE 802.3) Policies.
```

Answer (score 1):

My tests has revealed that on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 10, starting the *Wired AutoConfig* service (also known as "dot3svc") exposes the authentication tab; stopping it removes the tab.

Please note that starting this service is required even if you enforce authentication setting using Active Directory. Without this service, the settings won't take effect.